# PHP add new line \n into preg_replace_callback function

Tags: php

I am working with the `preg_replace_callback` function to add new line using PHP `\n`:

```
return preg_replace_callback( '|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', array( $this, 'autoembed_callback' ), $content );
}
```

Where can I put the `\n` into that function?

This function is to show embedded YouTube. When I type `wow like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DANYP9wXGi0` without entering the new line after 'wow like this', it won't show the video.

But if I type like this: `wow like this \n https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DANYP9wXGi0`, it will show the video.

Comment: Show your sample of input data and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not necessary callback function. You can in force insertion of `\n`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+https:/', "\nhttps:", $string);
```